# Does Nodejs gets slower with more no of concurrent users because of its inability to use more than one cpu core being single threaded

Tags: node.js, multithreading

How is nodejs good when u have 10000 concurrent users and only a single nodejs thread to serve all these
requests ? I know that processing will happen asynchronously but requests will be handled synchronously. So, Will the 9999th user and 10000th user have to wait till nodejs has received all the previous requests and fired respective non-blocking requests for all of them ? Doesn't this make nodejs slower when large no of concurrent requests hit the server and it can not spawn a different thread even when the single thread is overloaded ?

Comment: If you're serving a zillion users, then you likely use multiple clustered node.js processes.  node.js gains its scale because it is often more efficient for each CPU than threaded implementations, but if you have large scale, you will want to use multiple clustered node.js processes to take advantage of multiple CPUs.  Keep in mind that most servers are bottlenecked on some shared resource (like a database) anyway so that's usually where the scale limits come from, not from just the plain vanilla request processing.  But each app is unique in its demands on the system.

Comment: Thanks for the term  "multiple clustered node.js processes", I was not aware of it.

Answer (score 2):

At low level, there are quite many parameters which will together influence the inflection point of node performane:

1. Number of truly concurrent requests: if the requests are sufficiently distributed (as in a real workload scenario), the node thread will be ready to satisfy requests as and when they arrive. In contrast, if the number of true concurrent requests reaches the server system increases, as you indicated the sequential execution by single thread will start choking node.
2. If you measure performance of systems which implement blocking I/O models with a single thread dedicated for a single I/O, you may see a better result compared to node. However, when the concurrent requests go up, you will have to spawn dedicated threads in proportion to the concurrent requests, which eat up a lot of memory and CPU. Alternatively, you can use a thread pool, in which case the threads will incur performance loss due to context switching overheads. Finally one would improve the situation by using asynchronous I/O channels, where threads are not hard-bound to any sockets, rather work in socket channels. Node is a simple instance of the same.
3. Kernel I/O buffers can become overloaded which can further choke up the data flow, when the concurrent requests increases beyond limit.

At further lower levels, there can be much more. In short, yes - node will reach its inflection point (saturation and decline of performance) at some point in the load, not necessarily at exactly 10K requests, rather will depend on data flow rate, request rate, system resources, load in the system etc.

Ideally your suggestion to spawn new threads to handle requests make sense, but then the presence of multi-threads causes lot of new semantics in the language and lot of additional burdens in the node runtime, will offset the superior performance which it demonstrates at present.

A more practical solution is horizontal load balancing.

Hope this helps.